# MATLAB - transpose and extract a matrix in a line

Tags: matlab

```
old_mat = [1,2,3; 4,5,6];

new_mat = old_mat'(2:end, :);
new_mat = (old_mat')(2:end, :);
```

I would like to transpose and extract a matrix but I fail with these tries.

Is it possible to do them in a line?

Comment: You can first extract then transpose it . `old_mat(:,2:end).'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parentheses `( )` should usually<sup>[1]</sup> be the last thing in a Matlab expression. This is why an expression like `a(1)(1)` will give the error:

> Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

And your examples give the error

> Error: Unbalanced or **unexpected parenthesis** or bracket.

You should, as rahnema1 suggested, extract the columns and transpose rather than trying to transpose and extract rows.

```
new_mat = old_mat(:, 2:end).'
```

Note, I've used `.'` which is shorthand for [`transpose`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html), not `'` which is shorthand for [`ctranspose`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) and should be avoided unless specifically required!

---

[1] There are always exceptions to the rule! Here are examples of where you can put things immediately after `)`.

- Referring to table columns or struct fields by a string, where `T.('var')(1)` and `T.var(1)` are equivalent.
- Use the dot operator, which is again a feature of using structs, like `S(1).var`.

Generally though, if you're trying to add code next to a closing `)` for simple matrix operations then there is probably a syntax error.